# load testing website. What is needed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, load-testing

We are about to release an ASP.net MVC website in the near future. Im wrapping up functionality testing and now onto performance and load testing.

My question is how much load testing is appropriate? It is going to be a high traffic website. I looked at purchasing neoLoad but the cost is crazy. But there doesnt seem to be that many other good load testing software packages out there that test 1000+ users simulanuously.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the load test component of Visual Studio?
You need a licence for the Ultimate Edition of 2010 or the test edition or full suite for 2008.

Visual Studio 2010 is a better version as the licence component ([Visual Studio Load Test Virtual User Pack 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff520697%28v=msdn.10%29)) allows for the 1000 users to be spread across physical systems allowing for plenty of horsepower for each virtual user.

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition does come with 250 virtual users and our server (2.93GHz,2 processors 24GB ram) was able to generate 1300 https requests/sec using the tool.

The amount of load testing you require is proportional to the level of risk of having a sluggish application.

I would highly recommend using Visual Studio as your load testing tool.
Check out [Performance Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/performance-session-overview?view=vs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2015)
For more info and tips, [Ed Glas's blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/edglas/) is a great source.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say how much load testing is needed. How important is the project? What are the implications if the site goes down when it is launched? What if the site is very slow under high volume? Only you and your organization can answer how much testing is needed. The answer should be based on the cost of failure, rather than the perceived simplicity/complexity of the site. We've seen a lot of seemingly simple sites fail spectacularly under load.

Assuming that a successful site launch is relatively important, at least to you, I recommend:

1. Determine the workflows that account for 75% of your peak traffic load.
2. At an absolute minimum, try to simulate the page requests for those testcases
3. Be sure you account for think-times properly. Think time is the time between page requests - when the user is reading the page or filling out a form. Think times that are too long or too short will greatly affect the page request rate, and therefore your test results. Use randomized think times if possible.
4. It is tempting to leave out requests for static resources, since most web servers handle static content very efficiently. But if you have front-end load balancers, caching servers, etc, it is very important to test with those static resources - I can't tell you how many times we've seen sites break in this area.

There are a lot of alternatives for load testing software (our Load Tester product is similar to NeoLoad, but less expensive), but make sure you account for the full cost - that is the number of hours it takes you to get it working. There is a wide gulf in productivity in such tools. Tools like *ab* or *JMeter* have little up-front cost, but can quickly get expensive when trying to simulate traffic against sophisticated web apps, such as typical .NET apps.

You might also consider outsourcing the load testing. Of all development activities, load testing might be the easiest to outsource (we do it every day).

Answer (score 1):

If we've got the infrastructure setup to support it, we have shifted to using cloud based stuff such as [browsermob](http://www.neustar.biz/services/web-performance/load-testing). Its alot more realistic than most other benchmarks, especially for end-to-end performance.

Comment: Browsermob is now called Neustar.

Comment: And also got alot more expensive in the process . . .

Answer (score 0):

Try [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html).  It is designed for testing Apache, but should work great for any web server.